# Why is this function running, if I'm on a different tab (Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below seems to run, even though I'm on a different page and have set that as a condition:

```
function setItemListProductPg(){    
  var tabLists = "ArquivoItens";
  var tabValidation = "Painel do Produto";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabValidation);
  var arquivoItens = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabLists);
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var itemList = arquivoItens.getRange('B2:B');

  if(ss.getSheetName() === "Painel do Produto" && activeCell.getColumn() == 3 && activeCell.getRow() == 3){

  var arrayValues = itemList.getValues();  
   // define the dropdown/validation rules
  var rangeRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(arrayValues);

   // set the dropdown validation for the row
  activeCell.setDataValidation(rangeRule); // set range to your range

  }
  }
```

Could you let me know where this is failing?
Thank you!

Comment: I presume you set this up to run from an onEdit trigger. On edit triggers occur whenever a user edits any sheet in a spreadsheet so to be as efficient as possible you always want to minimize any of the code before you route the triggers around your code from the uninvolved sheets or tabs. That’s one of the reasons you should be using the information from the event object.

Comment: One of the main issues I'm working on right now is because the datavalidation that is to be o another page is being set on an undesired page. the range is the same though.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Because you are not querying for the active tab, only for the active spreadsheet

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabValidation);` will always retrieve the sheet with the name as specified in `tabValidation`, no matter if it is the active sheet or not.

Instead, you need to define:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
if(ss.getSheetName() === "Painel do Produto"...){
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
function setItemListProductPg(e){    
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="ArquivoItens" && e.range.columnStart==3 && e.value==3){
    var rangeRule= e.source.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];}));
    e.range.setDataValidation(rangeRule);
  }
}
```

And of course you will need to set the installable trigger manually via edit/Get Current Project Triggers.

Comment: I was just applying the above suggestion, when yours came in. I'll try this one on a new data validation to learn more about it. Thanks a million!